# Control m , scheduler exception without using calendar

Tags: calendar, scheduling, control-m

I am currently trying to schedule multiple jobs from Control m v 8.0 which all have different schedules but have only one item in common , they all should not be running for a single day lets suppose 25th December . 
I have looked for multiple options but all require calendar but i cannot use calendar for exception or scheduling .

Kindly let me know if there is anything i can use .